# MySQL JSON Array Column Count By Value

Tags: mysql, json

For example: create a JSON Array:

```
select JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('check1', "false", 'check2', 'false'), 
JSON_OBJECT('check2', "true", 'check3', 'true'),
JSON_OBJECT('check3', "false", 'check4', 'false')) as c1;
```

```
[{"check1": "false", "check2": "false"}, {"check2": "true", "check3": "true"}, {"check3": "false", "check4": "false"}]
```

The key is dynamic in each object. How to count how many value is false for each object once only?

I am using `JSON_SEARCH(array, 'all', 'false');`  It returns

```
["$[0].check1", "$[0].check2", "$[2].check3", "$[2].check4"]
```

I would like to get something like

```
[$[0], $[1]]
```

to get length is 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH

-- source data
cte1 AS ( SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('check1', "false", 'check2', 'false'), 
                            JSON_OBJECT('check2', "true", 'check3', 'true'),
                            JSON_OBJECT('check3', "false", 'check4', 'false')) c1),

-- search for specified value
cte2 AS ( SELECT JSON_SEARCH(c1, 'all', 'false') c1
          FROM cte1 )

-- parse searching result, count distinct elements
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', 1)) cnt
FROM cte2
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.c1 AS JSON),
                      "$[*]" COLUMNS ( value VARCHAR(254) PATH "$" )) jsontable;
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', 1)
```